# nginx php7.1-fpm.sock location

Tags: php, nginx

I'm getting an issue related with the location of /var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock.
I have the php installed:

```
php -v 
// PHP 7.1.17-1+ubuntu16.04. ......
```

But the problem is that the folder /var/run/ doesn't contains "php".
Also I've been searching for solution in the internet and I have a folder /etc/php/7.1, but it contains only next dirs:
apache2, cli, mods-available and there is no php7.1-fpm.sock.

Can you give me an advice of how can I find the location of this php7.1-fpm.sock ?

Thanks

Comment: Well did you install php-fpm?

Comment: Ah so its the separate module of the PHP? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, [Ubuntu Repo](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/php-fpm).